# Java - library question

Tags: java, dll, intellij-idea

I am using `QtJambi` port of `Qt` to `Java` and when launching my application it requires the corresponding `dll` files.

```
Loading library: 'qtjambi.dll'...
 - using 'java.library.path'

    at com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadNativeLibrary(Unknown
    at com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.trolltech.qt.Utilities.loadJambiLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.trolltech.qt.QtJambi_LibraryInitializer.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Library 'qtjambi.dll' wasn't found in PATH
```

Now, what would be the **best** way to configure my project *(in `IntelliJ IDEA`)* so that it would automatically use the provided `dll` files?

I don't want to modify the `PATH` or something like that, because I want this to be project-only solution, unrelated to the `OS` settings.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the Java system property `java.library.path` -- i.e.,

```
-Djava.library.path=/wherever/the/dll/is
```

Set this in the run configuration you use to launch your software.